# Как убрать повторяющуюся ссылку с одной из страниц в существующем react-приложении

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Мне нужно убрать одну конкретную ссылку из списка ссылок, которые повторяются в каждом разделе приложения. И в разделе В например (всего 4 раздела)  эту ссылку нужно удалить. У меня есть лишь небольшой опыт с react, буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Ну линки в футере

Comment: ispolzujete react-router-dom?

Comment: да, похоже что так.

Comment: Ispolzujte `useLocation` i proverajte tekushchij path. [More info](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/uselocation)

Comment: спасибо, буду смотреть